# Even though Apple Motion is used with FCP could I still use it with iMovie?

Tags: post-production, imovie

I don't want to get FCP just yet but I still want effects from motion.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Motion to create video that you would import into iMovie. That video could be things like lower thirds, titles, or other graphics with a transparent background, where you place it over other video. But Motion templates you create aren't seen or used by iMovie the way they are in Final Cut Pro.

Comment: So instead of making templates in motion, I could make videos to put in my project in iMovie?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant!

Comment: Also, iMovie supports alpha channels.  So if you export prores 4444 with alpha from Motion, you'll be able to layer it with transparency in iMovie.  But you really are missing out on a lot of control with FCPX, and it's not super expensive.